# Changing both Word Page Border Art Color

Tags: ms-word

Is it possible to change both Word Page Border Art Color? I'm using one with blue and black, and I could only manage to change the black thin outer line.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Answer (score 0):

With Interop, Microsoft released the [Borders Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.borders?view=word-pia).

There you'll find 2 members: `InsideColor` and `OutsideColor`, to return or set a value that indicates the 24-bit color of the inside/outside borders.